# Why is there an (apparent) difference in the max header length when degugging and when deployed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, http-headers, limit

I've run into a problem where a .NET 6 MVC app will fail with "HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long." when deployed in IIS but will work just fine in development. The headers are for sure *far* too large - we're working on making them smaller - but that doesn't explain why it would fail under IIS but not when debugging from VS. For added fun, it will fail with a smaller set of headers (headers about 12K) when in IIS than it has when it works in VS (headers about 20K). The largest headers by far are chunked auth cookies set by the standard `AuthenticationBuilder.AddCookie`.

I could understand more easily if it failed when debugging on localhost and not when deployed - all the cookies would be set on localhost and that could make it massive. It seems very strange that it is happening the other way around.

What might be causing the failure and/or how can I prevent it? Or some way to see what the header/request size limit that is being applied is in each case?

Changes to shrink the size of the auth cookie are in progress, but it would be good to know the underlying cause as well.

Comment: Headers are used to negotiate parameters that are used in the connection between client and server.When a client doesn't set a header the server uses a default setting which may be wrong.  Make sure when you compile you are updating both the Release and Debug Code.  Check dates of the executable in the bin folder to make sure you are updating all the executable files. You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to examine the http request and http response.HTTP Request/Response has three parts 1)URI 2)HTTP Headers 3)Body. Request may be bad and server thinks the body is part of the header.

Comment: @jdweng That might also explain some other odd behaviour I noticed yesterday - I was also getting ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR in a couple of browsers, but I put that down to a device-specific problem because it was only happening to one person.

Comment: the are three versions of HTTP 1) HTTP 1.0 - Stream Mode 2) HTTP 1.1 - Chunk Mode 3) HTTP 2 - an enhanced mode.  Older machines may not support HTTP 2.  Or there may be cookies already established that are causing conflicts.  A cookie is similar to a shortcut so every time you make a connection to same server you do not need all the headers.  When you upgrade code you sometimes have to delete the old cookies before code will work.

Comment: @jdweng I do know how HTTP works (well, broadly speaking; it's a while since I looked at the finer details). My question is specifically about why the server(s) involved might be acting differently given the same application code.

Comment: Not a surprise that many don’t know the essentials https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: The default browser in the user settings.  You can add the HTTP Header UserAgent which is override the default setting : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: IIS maximum size of HTTP header limit is 8K-16K. You can also refer to Header Limits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/headerlimits/. Troubleshooting HTTP 400 errors in IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-http-400-errors-in-iis.